# "This is it" vs "This it is"

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-order

A phrase like "This is it" is very common, but I've also heard people use "This it is" mostly with a slight hesitation between `This` and `it`, perhaps purely for pronunciation reasons.

I'm quite familiar with "This is it". It expresses conclusion of some kind like:

- the end of a thinking process
- a (final) choice
- a last episode

So what is the meaning of "This it is" ? I hope it's something more than just *Yoda-speak*.

Comment: It's probably something like "This *(is where)* it is"

Comment: Is there more after the "it is"?  I often hear "This... it is" at the start of an off-the-cuff remark or speech.  "This... It is not the job of the United States to..." or "This... it is a big problem if we can't make the software work for customer X.", etc.

Comment: Nothing appended. Just those 3 little words.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ***This it is*** as an idiomatic utterance, but ***That it is*** is a well established usage indicating complete agreement with a preceding (copula-based) assertion: *"Brrr! It's freezing out here!" "**That it is.** Let's go inside and get warm."*

Comment: "That it is" is the idiomatic expression for native speakers, but both are understandable. Possibly the people using "this it is" are native to a language where distance "this" (closer), "that" (further) is used when referring to *something*?

Comment: In similar vein, when a colleague found the spectacles that a third party was looking for, I heard the former ask *Are these they?* to which the owner replied *These they are!*

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not a native Englisher, to me, "this it is" seems like a regular structure, which in linguistics is called 'left peripheral focus'.

- There you go
- Here you are
- London it is (let's say you were applying for expat jobs around Europe, and finally you got on offer for London and you post it on social media)

Answer (score 0):

A person could say "..this...", show us an object, and continue the sentence or start a new one with "It is." Some examples that might work with this are:
"Now I want to show you *this*,*it is* an elephant skeleton." 
"Look at *this. It is* an exotic flower."
"Take *this. It is* used to wash your hair." (I thought this might work because you said they had a little pause).
Also, the person speaking could have lost their trail of thought or forgotten what they are trying to say.
For example, you could be trying to explain your science project to a class. You start saying "This...", but change your mind and say "It is....". You may do this because you forgot what you were going to say after this or because you found a better sentence to begin with "it is." 
The last thing that I think another user touched on as well is the form of speech "That it is.", which is a bit different. When you say 'that it is' you are saying "you're right, it is." For example, I could say "That is such a cute dog!" and you'd respond "That it is."